# OAuth 1.0 one-legged client "HTTP 401 Unauthorized error" for PATCH method

Tags: php, api, symfony, oauth

This is the first time I'm using OAuth and I created the class below which partially works! I followed [this manual](http://php.net/manual/en/oauth.fetch.php).

Methods `methodGet()` and `methodPost()` work fine however `methodPatch()` returns "HTTP 401 Unauthorized error". End-point expects a `PATCH` request method and since there [is no constant](http://php.net/manual/en/oauth.constants.php) for `PATCH` in [OAuth class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php), I'm trying to send a `POST` request and trying to override it with an extra `X-Http-Method-Override` header so that [it becomes](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/methodoverrides/) a `PATCH` method behind the scene (may be not!!!). That's the problem, I cannot PATCH it!

As it is highly likely to do with `PATCH` (GET and POST work fine), does anyone know a solution to it or am I missing something else?

Note: I can confirm that the end-point works fine so there is no problem at that side.

Thanks in advance

```
use Exception;
use OAuth;
use OAuthException;

class ApiClient
{
    // End-point accepts GET request - This works fine
    public function methodGet()
    {
        return $this->call(
            OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET,
            array('id' => 123)
        );
    }

    // End-point accepts POST request - This works fine
    public function methodPost()
    {
        return $this->call(
            OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST,
            array('name' => 'inanzzz')
        );
    }

    // End-point accepts PATCH request - This returns HTTP 401 Unauthorized
    public function methodPatch()
    {
        return $this->call(
            OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST,
            array('id' => 123, 'name' => 'inanzzz123'),
            ['X-Http-Method-Override' => 'PATCH']
        );
    }

    private function call($method, $params = array(), $headers = array())
    {
        try {
            $oAuth = new OAuth('api_key_goes_here', 'api_secret_goes_here');
            $oAuth->setNonce(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)));
            $oAuth->setTimestamp(time());
            $oAuth->setVersion('1.0');
            $oAuth->fetch(
               'http://api.domain.com/1/products/service.json',
               $params, $method, $headers
            );

            return json_decode($oAuth->getLastResponse(), true);
        } catch (OAuthException $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use Guzzle Client so the method is below:

Note: `$authHeader` holds `$oauth->getRequestHeader(...);` so you can generate it and pass it to the method.

```
private function call($uri, $method, $authHeader, array $payload = [])
{
    try {
        $client = new Client();
        $request = $client->createRequest($method, $uri);
        $request->addHeader('Authorization', $authHeader);
        $request->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $request->setBody(Stream::factory(json_encode($payload)));
        $response = $client->send($request);
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        $message = $e->hasResponse()
            ? $e->getResponse()
            : 'An unknown error occurred while trying to process your request.';

        throw new Exception($message);
    }

    return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
}
```